# Adding more realism to my rendering

Tags: rendering, texturing, photorealism

I've generated the bottle and labels, and am rendering in Cycles, but the result is looking too artificial. What can I add to the glass and label elements to make it look more realistic?

[image]

Comment: More subdivision levels, more roughness on the material, maybe also noise-based displacement or at least normal change. Add some HDRI as well.

Comment: Also a bit of glare and a bit of blur in the Compositor (or a bit of Depth of Field), a photo is never perfect with very sharp edges

Comment: As posed, this question does not have a definitive answer. What is 'realistic'  will depend on the environment you want to simulate? ... even if only in transmission/reflection. Could you provide some reference of the look you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Are you sure that the normals of the liquid are pointing outwards? I would give the sealing plug and the label a bit more texture, small noise texture and grooves for the plug, paper texture and a larger noise for the paper. Also give it a tiny bit thickness, and the rim a white texture, plus a few imperfections. For the glass, add a *Volume Absorption* node or [fake absorption](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/36430/107598) so the bottom where the glass is thicker becomes darker. Enable *Cycles > Film > Transparent* and *.. > Transparent Glass*, then "photoshop" the pure white background

Comment: For more realistic lights in *Cycles* try a spotlight with a [IES profile](https://ieslibrary.com/). Additionally, you can place a "diffusor" (a plane with random holes) in front of the light to create interesting shadows. 
Here an example with all mentioned tweaks:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGZRH.jpg